# NHibernate.Caches.EnyimMemcached, protobuf-net.Enyim want conflicting versions of Enyim.Caching

Tags: nhibernate, memcached, protobuf-net, enyim.caching

I'm trying to wire up NHibernate to use the Enyim.Memcached provider for its second-level caching.  Additionally, I want Enyim.Memcached to use the protobuf-net as its serializer.

Looking at nuget and the web, I can find pretty much all the pieces I need:

nuget:

- `protobuf-net.Enyim`
- `protobuf-net`  (dependency of protobuf-net.Enyim)
- `EnyimMemcached (Enyim.Caching)` v2.12  (dependency of protobuf-net.Enyim)

web:
(http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/files/NHibernate.Caches/ -- I couldn't find a nuget package for NHibernate.Caches.EnyimMemcached)

- `NHibernate.Caches.EnyimMemcached`
- `Enyim.Caching` v2.3

However, when I wire everything up, I get a `The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.` error.  The issue appears to be:

- `NHibernate.Caches.EnyimMemcached` wants `Enyim.Caching` v2.3
- `protobuf-net.Enyim` wants `Enyim.Caching` v2.12

They don't play nice.  I tried adding an assembly redirect, but to no avail:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Enyim.Caching" publicKeyToken="cec98615db04012e" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.3.0.0" newVersion="2.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

<strike>The "latest" Enyim.Caching assembly (via the EnyimMemcached package) only has v2.12.</strike> D'oh!  2.12 *is* more recent than 2.3. (Thanks for pointing that out Marc!)

Any thoughts?  Is there a NHibernate.Caches.EnyimMemcached nuget package I don't know about?  Or a protobuf-net.Enyim that uses 2.3 instead of 2.12?  I can't imagine I'm the only one that has tried to use this NHibernate-Enyim-Protobuf-net stack.  And I'm surprised the assembly binding redirect didn't fix the issue.

**UPDATE:** I'm good to go after following Marc's advice.  I simply downloaded the source of NHibernate.Caches.EnyimMemcached and changed its Enyim.Caching reference from the unsigned v2.3 assembly to the signed 2.12 assembly.  Everything's gravy!

Comment: Found more info and updated answer.

Comment: NHibernate caches `DictionaryEntry` objects which are only `[Serializable]` and therefore cannot take advantage of protobuf-net. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15959821/8799

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"only has v2.12" - this tripped me for a second there, but 2.12 is much more recent than 2.3; 2.7 is Jan 2011; 2.12 is Oct 2012. I don't seem to be able to get 2.3 at all (even via the command-line tools). There is no such thing as "only ... v2.12", ecause at the time of writing, v2.12 *is the most recent version*.

The simplest thing I can suggest, though, is to try building the protobuf transcoder manually, directly referencing whichever version it is that NHibernate works with.

There seems to be some... *oddness* surrounding the enyim tool; there are at least 2 different versions in the wild (with different strong names IIRC) - and they even have slightly different interfaces (`Int16` vs `Int32` in a few places, and `Flag` vs `Flags`, from memory). It *could* be that NHibernate is using the "other" one. I went with the build from nuget; but - if this is the "wrong" one, I'm happy to re-evaluate that.

Edit:

I downloaded NHCH-3.2.0.GA-bin.zip from your link, and used `sn -T <path>` to check the public key; this gives:

> {path removed}\Enyim.Caching.dll does not represent a strongly named assembly

I then tried this with the version freshly downloaded from nuget via `Install-Package EnyimMemcached`, which gives:

> Public key token is cec98615db04012e

So basically, at some point between 2.3 and 2.12, it has started using a strong name.

This means that these dlls will always have fundamentally different identity and can never be interchangeable. I can't do anything about that, sadly. If you can't update NH, then you will have to do a local build of the protobuf tool against the non-strong-named dll. If you get problems building it relating to a missing member `Flags`, try changing the code locally to `Flag`.

Personally, if it had been me, adding, removing or changing the public key token is worthy of a "major" revision update - i.e. going to 3.0; since that is fundamentally a breaking change.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the information!  It's unfortunate the entire stack doesn't work out of the box, but your insight gives me plenty to work with.